# How to get the same file path in the different build version

Tags: go

I have a file in different path between develop and production version, how to keep the same when i want to test them?

```
// In develop version, file in
~/project/assets/file

// In production version, file in
/service/assets/file
```

Comment: environment variables?

Comment: Command line flag that specifies root of assets dirctory?

Comment: Use config file that saves your environmental variables

Comment: You can also use build tags if you want it hard-coded, but specific for several binaries

Answer (score 0):

I like using a flag library like [alecthomas/kingpin](https://github.com/alecthomas/kingpin/tree/v2.2.6), which allows you to set a parameter like:

```golang
    env := ""
    appk.Flag("env", "Environnement (dev, qual, pprd or prod)").Envar("HOST_ENV").Short('e').Required().EnumVar(&env, "dev", "rct", "pprd", "prod")
```

Not only will you pass an environment name which is always correct (one of the four values "`dev`", "`rct`", "`pprd`", "`prod`"), but you can also *not* pass it directly, and it would still be detected through the system environment variable name "`HOST_ENV`"

You could also pass/set directly a file path/name.

But the idea remains: you can chose, with this library, between:

- a config file
- a parameter
- an environment variable